# aws public subnet ec2 pull image from ecr fail after add VPC interface endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, vpc-endpoint, aws-private-link

I use `aws ecr` to get login passwaord then pull docker image from private ECR at the public subnet EC2. This public subnet has already attached a internet gateway.

I already have an endpoint gateway for S3 before, so I created an interface endpoint for ECR (com.amazonaws.ap-southeast-1.ecr.dkr) follow the officail document, its subnet setting is the private subnet, also enable the private DNS.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html#test-interface-endpoint-aws

After that public EC2 can get password by `aws ecr`, but `docker login` fail, private EC2 cannot get password by `aws ecr`.
EC2s allow all outbound rules and no NACL setting, they IAM role combines the `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly` and S3 access permission that shown as below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::prod-ap-southeast-1-starport-layer-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Private EC2 `aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-southeast-1` error messags is

```
Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://api.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

Use `dig` showed the ip of `api.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com` is successful. I did not change any setting after created an interface endpoint. I don't know which step is wrong, please give me some suggestion. Thank you very much.

**Update**

I have a private VPC with 1 public subnet and 1 private subnet, each has it own route table, public subnet route table add internet gateway, private subnet route table add S3 endpoint.

**Secority group**
private subnet EC2

- Inbound rules: `source: sg-ALB, HTTP 80`, `source: sg-public-EC2, SSH 22`
- Outbound rule: `All traffic`

public subnet EC2

- Inbound rules: `source: All Ipv4, SSH 22`
- Outbound rule: `All traffic`

Public EC2 error meesage

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://xxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v2/": 
net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

**Update 2**
I have hosted a private zoned by Route 53 in this VPC, no sure that could be a problem or not.

Comment: What are security rules for the endpoint?

Comment: The sg is private vpc default security group.

Comment: I mean, you have to provide exact details of your setup. Your question lacks information. What **exactly** are your security groups, VPC setup, and more.

Comment: I had update as above, please give me some suggestion to fix this problem.

Comment: I use the NAT gateway replace the VPC endpoint, both EC2 work normally. But I still don't know what is wrong on VPC endpoint setting.

Comment: You haven't explain what are the SG of the interface. SG are interface specific, not bound to subnets. Thus writing "Secority group private subnet EC2" or similar does not explain anything.

Comment: The VPC endpoint's SG is default privae VPC SG, which inbound and outbound  both are `All traffic IPv4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoint is using `https`, which means you have to allow port **443** in your security groups.

Comment: Allow the `HTTPS/443` in inbound rule for two EC2 security groups?

Comment: I had update the security group that inbound rule allow `All traffic`, but it got the same error.

Comment: Thank a lot, I misused the security group setting.